# What is the difference between _imp and __imp?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, mingw

I came across an interesting error when I was trying to link to an MSVC-compiled library using MinGW while working in Qt Creator. The linker complained of a missing symbol that went like `_imp_FunctionName`. When I realized That it was due to a missing extern "C", and fixed it, I also ran the MSVC compiler with /FAcs to see what the symbols are. Turns out, it was `__imp_FunctionName` (which is also the way I've read on MSDN and quite a few guru bloggers' sites).

I'm thoroughly confused about how the MinGW linker complains about a symbol beginning with `_imp`, but is able to find it nicely although it begins with `__imp`. Can a deep compiler magician shed some light on this? I used Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: this is probably a side effect of MinGW's symbol decoration rules: http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm

Comment: I read that link before and was also confused by it. I see only one underscore there, which goes fine with the linker  error I received - but then I have to accept that now mingw suite is magically linking fine to my msvc dll which begins with `__imp`. That part is still unsolved.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is fairly straight-forward identifier decoration at work.  The `imp_` prefix is auto-generated by the compiler, it exports a function pointer that allows optimizing binding to DLL exports.  By language rules, the imp_ is prefixed by a leading underscore, required since it lives in the global namespace and is generated by the implementation and doesn't otherwise appear in the source code.  So you get `_imp_`.

Next thing that happens is that the compiler *decorates* identifiers to allow the linker to catch declaration mis-matches.  Pretty important because the compiler cannot diagnose declaration mismatches across modules and diagnosing them yourself at runtime is *very* painful.

First there's C++ decoration, a very involved scheme that supports function overloads.  It generates pretty bizarre looking names, usually including lots of ? and @ characters with extra characters for the argument and return types so that overloads are unambiguous.  Then there's decoration for C identifiers, they are based on the calling convention.  A cdecl function has a single leading underscore, an stdcall function has a leading underscore and a trailing @n that permits diagnosing argument declaration mismatches before they imbalance the stack.  The C decoration is absent in 64-bit code, there is (blessfully) only one calling convention.

So you got the linker error because you forgot to specify C linkage, the linker was asked to match the heavily decorated C++ name with the mildly decorated C name.  You then fixed it with `extern "C"`, now you got the single added underscore for cdecl, turning `_imp_` into `__imp_`.

Comment: Perfect! So logical, yet it takes someone who really understands to put it all together... thanks a bunch!