# GNU C++ import name mangling

Tags: gcc, name-mangling

I am working on a standalone php extension. After having problems on global (extern) variables I noticed that import libraries by Visual C (I never used VC and I have no idea on it) have named variables and functions differently. GNU compiler mangles both the same and no problem with functions. In dlls and libs variables have double underscores where as functions have only one. 
example; (pseudo)

```
#define EXT_API __declspec(dllimport)

extern "C"
{ 
EXT_API int func(void);
EXT_API extern int data;
}
```

gives (in lib/dll)

```
_imp__func

__imp__data
```

but GCC searches for

```
_imp__func  (OK)

_imp__data  (unresolved)
```

How can I configure GCC to mangle import names for data; like `__imp__name`?

Thanks in advance.

Note: My question is not on how compilers mangles functions. Functions and data has been compiled with the same options/preferences, but VC has made _imp__func and __imp__data. I am compiling both data and function on the same module with the same options (to match VC results) and GCC makes _imp__func and _imp__data. What am I missing with GCC?

Comment: Here's a great explanation which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236789/what-is-the-difference-between-imp-and-imp

Comment: What is the duplication id/link? How can I find the answer? If you mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236789/what-is-the-difference-between-imp-and-imp  it only explains how funcs are mangled, not the difference between func and data....

Comment: @İlhanÇELİK Data symbols aren't mangled for language/calling convention, code symbols are.